# Multistage OA, DC or AC coupled?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a multi stage OA amplifier (pulse applications) and I am not clear if better use AC or DC couple stages (C8 in this example). I removed caps for better response, charging and discharging through high resistors.

The REFH is VDD/2 and simulation looks nice but I question there would be a real (life) benefit by keeping caps or not.

[image]

Thanks for suggestions,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall you have a gain of 100 so if the DC value on your signal entering to the left of R10 is close to the value of REFH then there might be no advantage keeing C8. However, if the DC value at R10 is say 100 mV away from REFH then the final output will have an offset of 10 volts. Can you live with this offset on the output is what you should ask your self.

Comment: Hello Andy, I thought exact the same :) I have 4 stages, each one 10x and the final, must be capacitive coupled since I want to use REFL (little over GND), I need only positive pulses over maximal range (VDD). But before, the signal is low.

Answer (score 1):

Your high value resistors, and the total capacitance on the inverting inputs (pin3 is inverting), implement a significant phase shift and cause a risk of circuit oscillation or peaking.

If you alter the existing circuit ----- from simulation to breadboard or to PCB ------ the added capacitance [particularly pin3 to underlying GND plane] may make your life more exciting than you wish.

Those 10pF caps are "placekeepers", reminding you of the opportunity to tweak the pulse response in your final physical implementation.